# Implementing Image Lru Caching with DiskLruCache

Tags: android, bitmap, android-lru-cache

I am trying to implement Disk based image lru cache with jake wharton DiskLruCache library. [link to library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache). I am using a code snippet from [here](http://shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/09/memory-leak-and-out-of-memory-error_3.html).

Methods i am having trouble with are this

```
private boolean writeBitmapToFile(Bitmap bitmap, DiskLruCache.Editor editor)
        throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(editor.newOutputStream(0), Utils.IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
        return bitmap.compress(mCompressFormat, mCompressQuality, out);
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

where editor.newOutputStream(0) does not exist, and this one

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(String key) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    DiskLruCache.Snapshot snapshot = null;
    try {

        snapshot = mDiskCache.get(key);
        if (snapshot == null) {
            return null;
        }
        final InputStream in = snapshot.getInputStream(0);
        if (in != null) {
            final BufferedInputStream buffIn =
                    new BufferedInputStream(in, Utils.IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffIn);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (snapshot != null) {
            snapshot.close();
        }
    }

        Log.d("cache_test_DISK_", bitmap == null ? "" : "image read from disk " + key);

    return bitmap;

}
```

where snapshot.getInputStream(0) also does not exist.

What am i doing wrong? I have placed the jar with the library and all is well, are these methods deleted from DiskLruCache library? Is there other way to do this now? I can't find any examples or tutorials.

Library version is the latest disklrucache-2.0.2

Comment: Do you have the permissions to write to storage?

Comment: You mean the methods cannot be resolved?

Comment: yes, but what does that have to do with missing methods?

Comment: I didn't understand the issue at first.

Comment: How did you find out that the methods don't exist: from an editor highlight or at compile time?

Comment: editor highlighted them and it won't compile

Comment: Is the line import com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache at the top highlighted as well?

Comment: omg tnx man, i have seen now that it imported this com.squareup.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache instead of this com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have imported the right class:

`import com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache`